# Firbase analytics custom event parameter

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I use FireBase in my project and I want to log some custom event with my custom event parameters, but I wasn't able to find where I can setup my event parameters. When I try to look for it online, their Firebase console works differently from mine, probably because the tutorials is a few years old. But I really can't find it.

Logging event itself works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) I think that what you're looking for is located in **Analytics > Custom Definitions** as you can see below.

[image]

You should see a button called "Create custom dimensions".

[image]

By clicking on it you should be able to create your custom events.

[image]